# How to make jrxml in generic using jasper reports?

Tags: java, pdf, csv, jasper-reports, xls

I have implemented Jasper Reports in my application. But i have to make it generic ? please give me some suggestions?
for example,

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.columnHeader" value="columnHeader" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.columnFooter" value="columnFooter" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.pageFooter" value="pageFooter" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.lastPageFooter" value="lastPageFooter" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.summary" value="summary" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy" value="true" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.columnHeader" value="columnHeader" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter" value="Start" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.column.edge" value="Left" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.property.ignore.page.margins" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.font.size.fix.enabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
```

This peace of code is common for all jrxml files. i want to make it generic how?

Comment: I would suggest starting with iReport and look at how the reports are generated when iReport does it to learn what needs to be in the XML and what is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can move those common properties out of your jrxml files and into a properties file called `jasperreports.properties` (it must be on the classpath).

Instead of the XML format, it uses the standard Java properties file format, e.g.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.columnHeader=columnHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.columnFooter=columnFooter
# and so on...
```